# Oracle SQL Loader using batch and command file in windows 7

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, cmd, sql-loader

I am trying to automate the entire data loading from a flat file to a table in database in Windows 7 environment.

So, I created a windows batch file(Data_Load.bat) in `C:/Data_Load` folder. This takes the input as to which data has to be loaded. Once it takes the input, it will invoke the windows command file(Data_Load.cmd) in `C:/Data_Load/CMD_File`.

In the Data_Load.cmd, I gave the oracle `SQL*Loader` command. This loads the control file which is present in `C:/Data_Load/CTL_File`.

The `SQL*Loader` command in Data_Load.cmd file is given below.

```
sqlldr %_userName%/%_password%@%_serNm% 
      control=.\Data_Load\CTL_File\%_jobNm%.CTL
      log=.\Data_Load\CTL_File\%_jobNm%_%_datetime%.log
      bad=.\Data_Load\CTL_File\%_jobNm%_%_datetime%.bad > .\Data_Load\CTL_File\\%_jobNm%_%_datetime%.log 2>&1
```

Here `%_userName%`, `%_password%` and `%_serNm%` are the database parameters which I took the input in Data_Load.bat file.

After SQL Loader, I am using the below fine to notify an error.

set _rejrec=
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('findstr /x /c:"Total logical records rejected:         0" .\Data_Load\CTL_File\%*jobNm%*%_datetime%.log') do set _rejrec=%%G

IF "%_rejrec%"=="" (ECHO ECHO. !!!!!!! Errors in Load. Please check logs. Exiting. !!!!!!!
     PAUSE
     GOTO:EOF
     )else (echo CTL Load completed successfully !)
ECHO.

When I try to execute it, it throws an error in the log file :

```
 SQL*Loader-522: lfiopn failed for file (.\Data_Load\CTL_File\Account_Load_09_15_2014_0700AM.log)
```

I gave all the permissions("Full Control") to every folder and every file. It is weird to get this error. So, could you please let me know if there is anything I am missing in the program?

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: From which folder do you run it from?

Comment: If the batch file is in C:\Data_Load and you're executing it from there, don't the paths need to either be relative to that directory (e.g. `bad=.\CTL_File\%_jobNm%_%_datetime%.bad`), or if it's changed to `CMD_File`, `..\CTL_File\...`? Or the full path including the drive letter? The latter may be better anyway if this will ever be run automatically. It would certainly be clearer.

Comment: I am executing the batch file from the folder C:\Data_Load.

Yes Alex, I tried using the complete path in the .cmd file as well as in the CTL file. It gave me a similar error.
SQL*Loader-522: lfiopn failed for file (C:\Data_load\CTL_File\Account_Load_09_15_2014_0925AM.log)

Comment: Which user account is used to run sqlldr and the batch file? Is this done using a scheduled task which uses system account? The account used on running this batch file and SQL Loader must have write permission to the directory? And are you sure that there is no space anywhere in file name or path? It does not look so, but perhaps the spaces were omitted on output of error message.

Comment: I am using Windows Administrator user account to run the sqlldr file and batch files. 
It is not invoked using a scheduled task as of now. It is currently being invoked by double clicking the batch file. 
The account currently has full access on all the files and folders.